# How to prevent the ? character from causing a Bad URI Error in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get an eror because of a question mark. [Someone had the same problem but the answer that was given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748838/how-to-prevent-pipe-character-from-causing-a-bad-uri-error-in-rails-3-ruby-1-9-2) returns an error:

```
uninitialized constant URI::Parser (NameError)
```

This is my code (in a rackup file):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rack'
require 'time'
require 'set'
require 'uri'
require 'domain_constants'
require "digest/sha1"

URI::DEFAULT_PARSER = URI::Parser.new(:UNRESERVED => URI::REGEXP::PATTERN::UNRESERVED + '?')
```

Please help me get around this one, i've spent 4 hours trying to figure this one out.

PS:

The error i get in the first place is:

```
ERROR bad URI `/font/dorianclm-book-webfont.eot?)%20format("eot"),%20url(http://mysite.co:9292/font/dorianclm-book-webfont),%20url(http://mysite.co:9292/font/dorianclm-book-webfont'.
```

Comment: can you show how you get the error with a question mark? I've seen it with pipe(|) but just tried curling a few urls on an old app on 1.8.7 and I can't reproduce the error. Which web server are you using?

Comment: Do you have any control over the url construction? It looks like the double quotes are causing the issue (" -> subst with %22). This works for me: http://server/path?)%20format(%22eot%22),%20url(http://mysite.co:9292/font/dorianclm-book-webfont),%20url(http://mysite.co:9292/font/dorianclm-book-webfont)

Answer (score 1):

`URI::Parser` is Ruby 1.9 specific. Compare the URI module documentation:

- 1.8: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html
- 1.9: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html

And I bet you are using Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

The URI::DEFAULT_PARSER monkey-patch only works for ruby 1.9 (and is not a very desirable thing to have to do in the first place).

The URI module in 1.8 has the same issue, but it is much harder to patch without essentially re-writing big chunks of it.

If you are running into limitations of the default URI parsing, best course is to use something other than WEBrick (e.g. nginx).

Comment: I'm using Passenger behind apache, i can't upgrade to 1.9 nor i believe it's possible to change from WEBrick