# How to use square brackets [] in URI in Ruby HTTP request

Tags: ruby, http, net-http, typhoeus

I am using an API that requires me to issue a request to a URL with one of the fields passed as an array. For example:

```
"http://www.example.com/objects/add.php?key=XXXXXXXXXXX;objects=[%7B%2522field1%2522%253A%2522My%2520ObjectA2%2522%7D%252C%7B%2522field%2522%253A%2522ObjectB%2522%252C%2522color%2522%253A%25221%2522%252C%2522note%2522%253A%252298765%2522%7D];ids=foo,bar"
```

As you can see, the *contents* of the array should be URL-encoded, but the entire URL is not. Yes, I know it's odd, but it's the way the API is set up. When I enter the URI into Chrome and hit enter, it works, but when I use Typhoeus (or net/http) to encode the URI before passing it, it fails (the request goes through but the API doesn't recognize it properly).

How can I force Ruby to issue an HTTP request to this URI *without* URL-encoding the square brackets?

**EDIT**: This SO response looked promising, but I'm not entirely sure how I should alter the monkeypatching to fit this example.

[How do I monkey-patch ruby's URI.parse method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891158/how-do-i-monkey-patch-rubys-uri-parse-method)

Comment: Yes, some actual code would help. Also, check your Web server logs to see exactly what your request got translated to in both instances (Chrome versus Ruby).

Comment: @Krule: What makes it invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Typhoeus allows you to pass HTTP parameters using Ruby constructs. To produce a URL similar to the one in your post, you'd do something along the lines of:

```
my_params = { 
              api_key: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              objects: [
                { field1: 'My ObjectA2' },
                { field:  'ObjectB',
                  color:  '1',
                  note:   '98765' }],
              ids:  "foo, bar" 
            }


get_response = Typhoeus::Request.get("http://www.example.com/objects/add.php",  params: my_params)
get_response.effective_url #> http://www.example.com/objects/add.php?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ids=foo%2C+bar&objects=%7B%3Afield1%3D%3E%22My+ObjectA2%22%7D&objects=%7B%3Afield%3D%3E%22ObjectB%22%2C+%3Acolor%3D%3E%221%22%2C+%3Anote%3D%3E%2298765%22%7D
```

However, because your example URL contains a JSON object, it seems more likely that the API you're working with is looking for a POST request.

```
post_response = Typhoeus::Request.post("http://www.example.com/objects/add.php", params: my_params)
post_response.effective_url #> http://www.example.com/objects/add.php
post_response.request.params #> {:api_key=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", :objects=>[{:field1=>"My ObjectA2"}, {:field=>"ObjectB", :color=>"1", :note=>"98765"}], :ids=>"foo, bar"}
```

**EDIT:**

In the event that the API is expecting a GET request, currently the most common way to pass serialized data via GET requests is to append square brackets to the end of parameter names:

```
http://www.example.com/objects/add.php?objects[]=something&objects[]=something%20else
```

However, Typhoeus doesn't add brackets by default. There is some discussion [on the Typhoeus mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/typhoeus/lKXr88ImrN4) providing the reasoning behind this decision. Fortunately, you can easily add the brackets yourself:

```
my_params = { 
              api_key: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              :"objects[]" => [
                { field1: 'My ObjectA2' },
                { field:  'ObjectB',
                  color:  '1',
                  note:   '98765' }],
              ids:  "foo, bar" 
            }


get_response = Typhoeus::Request.get("http://www.example.com/objects/add.php",  params: my_params)
get_response.effective_url #> http://www.example.com/objects/add.php?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ids=foo%2C+bar&objects%5B%5D=%7B%3Afield1%3D%3E%22My+ObjectA2%22%7D&objects%5B%5D=%7B%3Afield%3D%3E%22ObjectB%22%2C+%3Acolor%3D%3E%221%22%2C+%3Anote%3D%3E%2298765%22%7D
```